# Jmeter phrasing the value

Tags: jmeter

I need to encrypt the below value:
encryption api is : url/api/enc/

{"login_user_id":"salem","Platform":"Android","AppVersion":"v2.1.17-uat 1.14.17","AppVersionCode":88,"BandWidthSpeed":"64","ApproxBandWidthSpeed":"10+ Mbps","device_id":"136e35b88a09cd16","BatteryStatus":"84","language":"en","Country":"","DeviceOffset":"19800","DeviceDateTime":"2022-09-14 11:00:40","UtcDateTime":"2022-09-14 05:30:40","NetworkType":"TYPE_MOBILE","NetworkSubType":"LTE","ip_address":"192.168.43.1","DeviceModel":"M2006C3MI","DeviceManufacture":"Xiaomi","DeviceOsVersion":"29","IMEI":"","analytical_url_status":"SUCCESS","analytical_url":`"api\/apply_weekoff"`,"analytical_time":"1703"}

I am passing all the parameters in the path by encoding such as { - %7B, } -%7D and " with % 22

But i am getting error with -  "analytical_url":`"api\/apply_weekoff"` this part / i have tried with `\-%5C` & `/ with %2F` but it is not working
Is there any suggestion to convert the values of `\/`

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

You can use [__urlencode() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode) like

```
${__urlencode("analytical_url":"api/apply_weekoff")}
```

and you will get

```
%22analytical_url%22%3A%22api%2Fapply_weekoff%22
```

[image]

If you want to change the value in the response from `apiaply_weekoff` to `api\/apply_weekoff` you can use [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) to replace it on the fly and substitute the response

```
def response = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())

response.analytical_url = 'api\\/apply_weekoff'

prev.setResponseData(new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(response).toPrettyString(),'UTF-8')
```

Comment: i have edited my query and as you said i have tried with - %22analytical_url%22%3A%22api%2Fapply_weekoff%22 but it is not working the request is not success. Using the same encryption api i can encrypt other the things is   \/ this parameter is confusing